General form of finite partitions of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$.
Is the following statement true? If so, how does one go around proving it?
"Let $\alpha$ be a finite partition of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$, then there exists a finite subset of the integers $K \subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\alpha$ can be written as the collection of sets with the following structure: $A = \{ (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}|\, \forall k \in K, x_k = a_k\}$, with $a_k$ a given sequence of elements of $\{0, 1\}$, save for sets of measure zero."
The measure is the uniform Bernoulli measure, that is the product measure defined on the cylinders by $\mu(\{ (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}|\, \forall k \in K, x_k = a_k\}) = 2^{-|K|}$. It ocurred to me this could be true, and it would help me prove a subsequent result, but I don't know how it could be proven.

Can you clarify what you mean by "save for sets of finite measure?" Do you mean to say "infinite?" I ask because it seems all sets $A$ you mention are cylinders, and therefore have finite measure.

Sorry, I will fix that. I meant sets with zero measure. I also have a typo with the definition of the Bernoulli Measure. Thanks for noticing!

By "save for sets of measure zero", do you mean that you're working "modulo null-symmetric-differences"? If so, try first looking for a counterexample in ${0, 1}^2$...

I'm not sure. What I mean is that elements of the partition which are not cylinders would necessarily have measure zero. Is there a counterexample in ${0, 1}^2$?

Yes, there is a counterexample. The "partition" thing is a bit of a red herring - start by just finding a set which is not a cylinder set...

Have you thought about what happens if your partition is simply an unmeasurable set and its complement?

@CiaránÓRaghaillaigh You are absolutely right, there can be an unmeasurable set and its complement. Thank you!

Any cylinder set has measure $2^{-n}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$. But for any prescribed number $0<\alpha <1$, there are subsets of $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ that have measure $\alpha$. For example, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$, let
$$A_n:=\{x\in\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}} \mid x_k=0 \text{ for }k=1, \dots, 2n-1,\ x_{2n}=1\}.$$
The $A_n$'s are pairwise disjoint and for the set $A:=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ we have $\mu(A)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{1}{3}$. Since $\frac{1}{3}$ is not equal to $2^{-n}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$, for any cylinder set $C$ we have $\mu(A\triangle C)\neq 0$.

...but there are "simpler" counterxamples like ${x \mid x_1=x_2=0}\cup {x \mid x_1=x_2=1}$.
